# new column in dataframe derived from second dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've two dataframes df1 and df2.I've to add a new columns in df1 from df2 :

```
     df1          
    X Y Z      
    1 2 3        
    4 5 6        
    7 8 9        
    3 6 9       
    
    df2
   col1 col2
   XX    aa
   YY    bb
   XX    cc
   ZZ    vv
```

The values of col1 in df2 should be added as new column(if it does'nt exists) in df1 and col2 as value of new column.For example :

```
    df1              
    X Y Z XX  YY  ZZ   
    1 2 3  aa  bb vv    
    4 5 6  cc           
    7 8 9               
    3 6 9               

     df2
   col1 col2
   XX    aa
   YY    bb
   XX    cc
   ZZ    vv
```

Comment: Why are aa, bb and vv associated with df1 row `1,2,3` and cc with row `4,5,6`?
Don't forget that in spark, the principle is that each row is distributed. There is no order. So you cannot say "the 1st row" for example

Comment: I just realise: `val def = ...` !?! `def` is a keyword in scala :)

Comment: @Juh_ Is it clear now ? df1 and df2 are two different dataframe.I've changed the name of new dataframe :)

Comment: About aa,bb and vv,these are the values getting added in new column and it's relation is from df2 XX - > aa,cc , YY -> bb etc

Comment: You didn't get my question: what rule decide that `aa bb vv` should be on the same row as `1 2 3`, and not on the row `7 8 9`, for example? To attach data on a row, you need a rule to decide which one

Comment: There's no such rule,aa bb vv can be added anywhere.I was just giving out example.My main goal is to create new column from df2.

Comment: I can tell you how to add column in df1 from values from `df2.col1`, but I have no idea how to select which values from `df2.col2` to put inside

Comment: That would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, spark dataset are made to be distributed. But column name are part of the schema, so they are in memory of the master. Thus, to add columns for each distinct values of `df2.col1`, you first need to get those values in the master (i.e. collect)

```
// inputs
val df1 = List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (3,6,9)).toDF("X", "Y", "Z")
val df2 = List(("XX", "aa"), ("YY", "bb"), ("XX", "cc"), ("ZZ", "vv")).toDF("col1", "col2")

val newColumns = df2.select("col1").as[String].distinct.collect

val newDF = newColumns.foldLeft(df1)( (df, col) => df.withColumn(col, lit("?")))
newDF.show

+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  X|  Y|  Z| ZZ| YY| XX|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  ?|  ?|  ?|
|  4|  5|  6|  ?|  ?|  ?|
|  7|  8|  9|  ?|  ?|  ?|
|  3|  6|  9|  ?|  ?|  ?|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

But

- I don't know what values you want to put in those column (above, I put "?" everywhere)
- if there are a lot of rows in df2, like 10's of thousand, it can kill the master to collect and add them all to df1

Now, to give a little more, here is how you can add columns from df2.col1 and put as values the concatenated values of df2.col2

```
val toAdd = df2.groupBy("col1").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_set("col2")).as("col2All"))
toAdd.show

+----+-------+
|col1|col2All|
+----+-------+
|  ZZ|     vv|
|  YY|     bb|
|  XX|  cc,aa|
+----+-------+

val newColumns = toAdd.rdd.map(r => (r.getAs[String]("col1"), r.getAs[String]("col2All"))).collectAsMap()

val newDF = newColumns.foldLeft(df1){ case (df, (name, value)) => df.withColumn(name, lit(value))}
newDF.show

+---+---+---+-----+---+---+
|  X|  Y|  Z|   XX| YY| ZZ|
+---+---+---+-----+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|cc,aa| bb| vv|
|  4|  5|  6|cc,aa| bb| vv|
|  7|  8|  9|cc,aa| bb| vv|
|  3|  6|  9|cc,aa| bb| vv|
+---+---+---+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: cc should be added as a distinct row in XX.
`xx  yy   zz
  aa  bb   vv
  cc.  null  null `

Comment: It worked.I did'nt aggregate the data.Thanks